# Trying to display the nested object in react

Tags: json, reactjs

I have tried the below code to display the nested values ,but got the parsing error.Please check the link to see the object

> Line 116:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

```
render(){
    return(

               {this.state.SearchBooks.map(book => 

                <h1>{ book.bookname}</h1>
                {book.assignedto.map(assbook=>
                  <h1>{assbook.userid}</h1>
                )}

               )} )}
```

[This is the object present in firebase i have stored it in this.state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7fhU.png)

Comment: You started some JS in your `<h1>`, didn't finish it.

Answer (score 1):

Your curly braces are not balanced:

`{book.assignedto.map(assbook => <h1>{assbook.user,id</h1>)}`

should be

`{book.assignedto.map(assbook => <h1>{assbook.user},{id}</h1>)}`

or, following your edit/correction:

`{book.assignedto.map(assbook => <h1>{assbook.userid}</h1>)} // the } after userid`

Last, you need to wrap it all by a top level element, so add a fragment:

```
    <>
      <h1>title</h1>
      {book.assignedto.map(assbook => <h1>...</h1>)}
    </>
```

Comment: Does it still complain after your correction? What error do you get?

Comment: I have corrected it. But still getting the same error.

Comment: What version of react are you using?

Comment: "react": "^16.9.0"

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
{this.state.SearchBooks.map(book => (
      <h1>{ book.bookname}</h1>
      {book.assignedto.map(assbook => <h1>{assbook.userid}</h1>
)}
```

To:

```
{this.state.SearchBooks.length && this.state.SearchBooks.map(book => (
    // add this
    <>
       <h1>{ book.bookname}</h1>
       {book.assignedto && book.assignedto.map(assbook => <h1>{assbook.userid}</h1>
    // and this
    </>
)}
```

Comment: TypeError: book.assignedto.map is not a function , changed it but got this error.

Comment: Is there a possibility that `book.assignedto` is sometimes not defined? see my updated answer how to check for that before mapping over it.

Comment: It's displaying the bookname , but not the nested values(assbook.userid)

Comment: Is it possible that `book.assignedto` is an object and not an array? map only works on arrays not on objects.

Comment: book.assignedto is an object SearchBooks is an array

Comment: I converted it to a array but getting the values as 1for sub elements. I think it's returing bool